# Dropdown sorted by categories

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to build a dropdown with items sorted by categories using Material-UI, something like:

```
Category1 (not clickable) 
test1 
test2 
Category2 (not clickable) 
test3
test4
```

I have tried the below but the `Select` componnent doesn't accept the two `maps`.
Any idea how can I achieve that?

```
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select'
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem'

    <Select value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
      {items.map(item=> (
             <MenuItem value="">
                <em> {item.category}</em>
             </MenuItem>
          {item.tags.map(i=> (
            <MenuItem value={i} key={i}>
              {i}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
      ))}
    </Select>
```

Comment: You have to go with react dropdown tree select, Select is not option for this purpose which you are trying.

Comment: The select is a material-ui component, there is no way to add subheaders to it?

Comment: @user3378165 did you have any luck integrating this feature?

Comment: I didn't look how to do the select, but that code doesn't work not because of the maps but because there is a missing parent element. If you wrap the first MenuItem and the second map in a fragment (<></>) it will work.

Comment: @PedroBrost It won't work, material-ui select doesn't accept a fragment.

Comment: @ChristopherNgo not really :(

Comment: @user3378165 I don't know why but using <React.Fragment> instead of <> works

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue myself. Fragments in either syntactical form don't work either. Questions a little old but for others who have this problem here is the workaround I used.

Build the list of MenuItem components you want in the body of your component, not in the return function. Then insert this list into the return jsx of your component.

For example:

```
export default myComponent = ( props ) => {

  const menuItems = []  // build the list of menu components
    allThings.forEach( (v, index) => {
    if( somecondition is met) {
      menuItems.push(<Divider/>)
    }
    menuItems.push(<MenuItem style={{display: ""}} key={index} name={v.name} value={index}>{v.name}</MenuItem>)
  })

return (
  <Select 
  value={vendorIndex}
  onChange={( event ) => {onChangeHandler( event )}}
  id="select">
    {menuItems}  // We insert the list here
  </Select>
)
```